# How to protect electrical parts from heating coil

Tags: heat, coil, batteries, lithium, heat-protection

I'm trying to diy an electric lighter with a 3.7v lithium battery, an on\off switch, and a micro lipo usb charger.

Already connected the coil and everything works as expected.

The only problem I have is creating an enclosure for this thing. I want to try and make it the size of a USB stick or a key.

But I have no idea of what materials to use to protect the electronics from the heat. How far away do I need to mount the lithium battery?

Is there some coating or isolation I can add to dissipate the heat better ?

Am I over thinking it? (As an electric lighter is on for just a second or two and the heat generated is very short time wise)

Would making the enclosure metal help dissipate the heat? Or will the casing just heat up to an unpleasant temperature?

Help would be appreciated :-)

Comment: I guess a lot of the heat will be radiation based, so you could get a sort of heat shield by a simple shining metal (you can try aluminium foil for a start). This will reflect most of the radiation and prevent it from heating your device. Make sure it doesn't short out anything. Your battery should stay below 40 °C for best performance.

Comment: You're not overthinking it, the batteries are quite flammable. I'd suggest a thermoset plastic case inside a metal outer shield.